# How do I best obfuscate HTML/Javascript/WebGL code?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

I have some HTML/Javascript/WebGL code that I would like to obfuscate.
My code consists of one .html file, several .js files and GLSL code embedded in the .html file.

I have found the tool [UglifyJS](https://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs) that I can use to obfuscate the .js files one by one.
I have also found the tool [GLSL Compiler](http://glslunit.appspot.com/compiler.html) that I can use to obfuscate the GLSL code.

There is two problems with this approach:

1. It is partly manual. I have to cut and paste and edit.
2. Since the GLSL Compiler do not obfuscate .js it can not change the
   name of uniform variables in the GLSL. Also if I paste one file
       containing a function into UglifyJS it will not change the name of
       the function since it does not know where it is called from.

Is there any tool or combination of tools that would give me a less manual and more complete obfuscation?

Answer (score 1):

For JS I have always loved this script:

http://jsutility.pjoneil.net

I have multiple files of JS, running this as a batch script it combines all the files into a single file, obfuscates them, compacts them and then compresses them. It works great. I have got over 2mb of javascript to compress down to around 350kb using this plus its free!

Quick example, download code from website and then create a wsf file with roughly this.

```
<job id="ObfuscateJavascript">

    <script language="VBScript">
        Function WSHInputBox(Message, Title, Value)
            WSHInputBox = InputBox(Message, Title, Value)
        End Function
    </script>

    <reference object="Scripting.FileSystemObject" />
    <script language="JScript" src="JSUtility_BatchCodeC.js" />
    <script language="JScript">

        var vbOKOnly = 0;
        var vbInformation = 64;
        var title = "What Project are you building for?";
        var prompt = "Enter a file name:";
        var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
        var result = WSHInputBox(prompt, title, "FileName");

        if (typeof result != "undefined") {
            InputFiles.push("File1.js");
            InputFiles.push("File2.js");
            InputFiles.push("File3.js");

            // Obfuscation options
            Obfuscate.Options = {
                DefinedGlobalVars: true, 
                ObjectMembers: false, 
                StringVariables: true, 
                MinimumStringLength: 12, 
                RestructureIfStmts: true
            };

            // Compaction options
            Compact.Options = {
                AddMissingSemicolons: true, 
                LeaveNewLines: false, 
                LeaveNewLineAndComment: false, 
                RemoveUnnecessarySemicolons: true
            };

            // Compression options
            Compress.Options = {
                ISO8859Compatable: true, 
                UTF8Compatible: true
            };

            // File output
            OutputFile = result + ".min.js";

            // Operations to apply to javascript
            Operations = {
                Validate: false, 
                Obfuscate: true, 
                Compact: true, 
                Compress: true, 
                StopOnWarning: false
            };

            JSUtilityBatch();
        }

    </script>
</job>
```

Then I create a bat file with this:

```
Script WSFFileNameYouUsed.wsf
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the GLSL files in external sources. I understand this should increase the total loading time of the website (more requests) but in our case it's not really noticeable. Besides, a 3D application needs to download (and process!) a lot of data anyway when loading.

As for renaming uniforms I don't think you can safely do that without disrupting some use cases. You could use pattern matching but you'd have to give your uniforms very specific names and even then you have to watch out those new names don't interfere with existing ones. It's similar to UglifyJS not changing the names of fields inside objects.